# Rails Admin accepts_nested_attributes with belongs_to hides search select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I'm using model with two belongs_to associations with Rails Admin.

```
belongs_to :product, inverse_of: :services
belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :services

accepts_nested_attributes_for :product, allow_destroy: true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user, allow_destroy: true
```

Adding `accepts_nested_attributes_for` makes generated form look like this without select for search in existing records.

[image]

Without `accepts_nested_attributes_for` it looks exacly as I want it to

[image]

Is there a way to force Rails Admin use search select?

```
field :user do
  nested_form false
end
```

doesn't work as I expected.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but I'd look into ActiveAdmin instead. I used RailsAdmin for a while, and stopped when I ran into issues similar to this. There's such thing as too much magic.

Answer (score 1):

Well

```
field :user do
  nested_form false
end
```

actually works fine. I was just using it in list block instead of edit... sigh